# Video in YouTubePlayerView pausing after 2 sec in android phones

Tags: android, youtube

I am loading video in **YouTubePlayerView**(in android device).
Initially it plays for 2 seconds and stops by showing play button on it.
If again I press play button , video plays for 2 sec and get paused.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same behavior and the error "UNAUTHORIZED_OVERLAY," but this actually had nothing to do with the solution I eventually found. I wasn't overlaying the video with anything, and had the padding was 0. My problem was that the targetSdkVersion was set to 26. I reduced it to 19 and it works now. This took forever to track down, so hopefully this will save someone else some time.

tl;dr: Reduce the targetSdkVersion in your app's build.gradle to 19

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the size of the YoutubePlayer view is atleast 200x110 dp like descriped in the Youtube API documentation. Sounds like it doesn't meet those requirements when in landscape mode.

**Youtube API documentation**

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView

Comment: **Thanks a lot.**
Problem was I had small image view on video.
I have removed that view and bang on..
Video is playing very smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Add margins to the wrapper view around the youtube view,I did this and added margin both vertically and horizontally and the error was fixed.